# open a terminal in vim and execute a command inside this terminal on windows

Tags: vim

I would like to execute a command in vim's terminal as soon as it is opened.
tried this but it didn't work:

```
    nnoremap <leader> t: below split <bar>: resize 14 <bar>: term ls <CR>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  You said it didn't work, but how exactly?

Comment: is because the ls command is only present in the windows powershell and apparently vim is using the command prompt

Comment: To switch vim's default shell to Powershell, you can use `:set shell=powershell shellcmdflag=-c shellquote=\" shellxquote=`. Alternatively, you can change `ls` to `dir`.

Comment: @LucasMartinsSoares - Not sure what your aim is but try `:vert 50sp.` instead of using the terminal to show you a directory listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch vim's default shell to Powershell, you can use :set shell=powershell shellcmdflag=-c shellquote=" shellxquote=. Alternatively, you can change ls to dir.

@Lieven Keersmaekers